# delete_user hook failed

Tags: hooks, users

I would like to delete a specific post when the user is deleted in `admin/users.php`.

I did this code :

```
add_action('delete_user', array(__CLASS__, "delete_user_profile"), 10 ); //I´m sure the code passed by here.

public static function delete_user_profile( $user_id ){
    var_dump( $user_id ); //Never called
    wp_die( "delete_user_profile");

}
```

What could be the problem ? Is there a different way or hook to do this ?

Comment: is that code inside a class? If so, please paste the whole class

Comment: Yes, it is in a whole class, but it´s a class with 570 lines called by other class so difficult to put all this code or clear code to be understanding but thanks because your question helps me to try something and perhaps to be on the right way.

Comment: does the class extend another class?